# Memory cards on computers instead of hard disk

Tags: memory

Why dont we use memory cards on computer.A memory card is a data storage device which can hold data even not powered and can be erased and reprogrammed electrically.

Comment: We do, they're called SSD's... but classically we've used motorized drives as they're more cost effective per GB, and high-capacity memory cards are a fairly new technology.

Comment: You seem to be asking a lot of basic questions about computing. Please first do some research before asking questions on this site. Your account might be blocked from asking further questions if they keep getting closed or downvoted.

Comment: Take a look at netbooks and tablet computers.  They often have a flash memory card as their primary storage and may offer a memory card socket for expansion.  Standard memory cards don't do wear leveling so they don't have the service life of a hard disk for that kind of usage.

Answer (score 0):

There are various trade offs with your general statement.

First of all there are multiple types of memory cards you could be referring to. Memory cards for consoles (PlayStation, GameCube and so on), SDHC cards, CF cards and a whole slew of other [formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_card) exists.

Each of these has particular advantages and disadvantages. As you already said most/all will store information if not powered but will they do so infinitely are there restrictions on the number of times data can be written or read? It depends on the format.

What currently comes closest, as a comment pointed out, are SSDs. The commong thing among memory cards being that they don't rely on mechanic parts to store information. The downside is that the data density is usually lower in addition to other restrictions. Even with SSDs you will find numbers on how many read/write cycles an SSD can take.

In the end it depends on what scenario you're looking at what storage type is going to be the best fit. Want to store thousands on gigabytes of data? Access can be slow and doesn't need to be transportable? Or is it the opposite? Highly mobile with little data volume and lightning fast access?

Comment: Yeah but hard discs take time to store data due to mechanical limitations for example the disc cannot rotate infinitely fast.

Comment: "data density is usually slower"?

Comment: corrected. @Altair Yes but as mentioned those are the trade offs. Storing 1 PB of data on an SSD is going to cost a lot of money. Currently the price per gigabyte is around 0.25 US Dollar per GB for SSDs and 0.04 US Dollar per GB for HDDs. There are advantages and disadvantages to both approaches. Unless you pose a specific scenario both are valid technologies.

Comment: @Altair, memory cards aren't infinitely fast, either.  For them to reuse space is a slow process.